# Can't restart music as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a button that turns on and off the music. When I turn it off it works, but when I try to play again the music it doesn't work! help please

```
var sound=true;
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("Track.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();

function changeSound(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(sound==true){
    myChannel.stop();
        sound=false;
    }
    if(sound==false){
    myChannel.reset();
    sound=true;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SoundChannel` doesn't have a `reset` method. Call `play` instead of `reset`.

```
if(sound==false){
    myChannel = mySound.play();
    sound=true;
}
```

Also, you should place `else` between two `if`.

```
if(sound==true){
    myChannel.stop();
    sound=false;
}
else if(sound==false){
    myChannel = mySound.play();
    sound=true;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work. But I have a solution: I have to save the "position" of the music. I t works now. But thanks!